# Hibernate/Sleep problem

Tags: sleep-wake, hibernate

Whenever my MBP 9.1 is in sleep mode and plugged in and I unplug the charger, machine turns on and stays on for about 2 minutes and then gets to sleep again.

Is there something I can change so when it's in sleep mode and I unplug or plug charger, stays at that state and doesn't hibernate or hybrid sleep or whatever it's name is given by Apple?

I basically want to disable hibernate altogether by automatic means.

My OS X version is 10.9.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Energy Saver. Change the sleep settings for both on Battery and While charinging.
[image]

Alternatively you could use [NoSleep](https://code.google.com/p/macosx-nosleep-extension/) to make sure your MBP never goes to sleep.

Comment: I do want the machine to go to sleep, I don't want it to go to hibernate mode, i.e. writing memory's content on hard disk, which takes a lot of time and prevents me to unplug the machine and be good to go.

Comment: @user3249323 check your mode by running this command on terminal > pmset -g | grep hibernatemode

Comment: It returns 3 which as I searched is default for modern MBP's.

So how can I have sleep when I close the lid but no hibernation or basically any activity that writes memory content on hard disk? hibernate mode 0?